# Convert date type (Sun Apr 01 00:00:00 UTC 2018) in excel VBA as a custom function

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I need to create a custom function based on the formula:
`=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(MID(A2,8,3),MID(A2,4,4),RIGHT(A2,4)))`

where A2= `Sun Apr 01 00:00:00 UTC 2018`

And the result should be: `43191`

I also need that this function will be available anywhere in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function MyDate(val As Variant)
    MyDate = DateValue(Mid(val, 8, 3) & "-" & Mid(val, 4, 4) & "-" & Right(val, 4))
End Function
```

so you can type in any cell `=MyDate(A2)` (or whatever, cell reference you need)

Comment: EXACTLY what I needed. Thanks a lot.